# Zsh function sublime open folder and directory

Tags: shell, sublimetext3, zsh, zsh-alias

I'm trying to write a zsh function for open files or folders from terminal.

```
function osub () {
if [[ -z $@ ]]; then
  /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl $@
else
  /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .
fi
}
```

I try with $1 also. I want to open current folder in sublime if run only osub command and create new file and open it on sublime if run osub filename

Comment: If my answer helped you then please upvote it as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check that `$@` is non-zero instead of zero which `-z` does. So

```
if [[ -n $@ ]]; then
```